# Winch with String

Tags: technic, piece-usage

I'm considering buying a few [winch's with string](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2584c02#T=C). I don't understand what I need to make it turn. It doesn't look like a regular technix axle goes inside it right?  I've looked at a few of the instructions for sets it's supposed to be in and I can't find where it's used.   What parts do I need to purchase with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually *does* take a Technic axle and has been used with such in some sets, although in most old sets I know it was usually supposed to be operated manually by rolling the drum with your fingers.

If you look at the picture of the [individual drum piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2585&idColor=0#T=S&C=0&O=%7B%22color%22:0,%22iconly%22:0%7D), you can just about see the axle holder inside, even though the round hole itself is bigger. So you can stick a normal Technic axle into it and do whatever you want with it, but this really depends on the actual build you're trying to accomplish and nothing precludes you from simply making it hand-operated either.

From 2019 set [60216](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60216-1&name=Downtown%20Fire%20Brigade&category=%5BTown%5D%5BCity%5D%5BFire%5D#T=I):

[image]

Comment: I looked at the 3d render of the piece and I can see how the axle fits into it now. Thanks